# Elasticsearch Need to get matched fields from document on querying

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to get only matched fields from returned document on search.

Here is my sample index:

```
{
    "_index" : "company",
    "_type" : "data",
    "_id" : "1",
    "_version" : 1,
    "found" : true,
    "_source" : {
        "cpn" : "companycpn",
        "cpn_desc" : "_NA",
        "mpn" : "2-020 TFE_Tri",
        "commodity_name" : "_NA",
        "sub_commodity_name" : "HARDWARE & MISC",
        "manufacturer_name" : "PARKER HANNIFIN",
        "supplier_name" : "ABCDE",
        "product_name" : "NA",
        "product_description" : "NA",
        "product_family_name" : "NA",
        "cm_odm_name" : "CRF",
        "fiscal_year" : "2015",
        "fiscal_quarter" : "1"
    }
}
```

Here is the GET query which I am using:

```
GET company/data/_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "*parker*"
        }
    },
    "size": 10
}
```

If you observe for the above query the matched field 'manufacturer_name' in _source. I need to get only this field, i.e I want to get only matched fields for the given query from elasticsearch.

Is there any way for this ?